# Cannot access state inside a timer in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I started a timer and want to stop it if the state of isPaying changes to false

```
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false)
  const isPlayingRef = useRef(isPlaying);

  const play = () => {
    setIsPlaying(true);
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if(!isPlaying){
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
      console.log('isPlaying ', isPlaying);
      console.log('isPlaying ', isPlayingRef.current);
    }, 5000);
  }
```

Both `isPlaying` and `isPlayingRef.current` are false inside the timer despite that I am setting the value to true in the play function.

Comment: can' see any `isPlayingRef.current = true` in your `play` function :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: `isPlayingRef.current` will always be `false` since it is set only once, where `isPlaying` is `false`

Comment: I switched to the hook UseInterval which woks like a charm https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-interval